# Prove that $Tv_1,...,Tv_n$ is linearly independent in $W$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Suppose $T \in \mathcal{L}(V,W)$ is injective and $v_1,...,v_n$ is linearly independent in $V$. Prove that $Tv_1,...,Tv_n$ is linearly independent in $W$.

I generally follow the solution below:
[image]

**But I don't understand the line "Because $T$ is injective, this implies that $a_1v_1 + ... +a_nv_n = 0$". How injectivity implies the formula?**

And my trial to this question is something in reverse order.

I started with

$$0 = a_1v_1 + ... + a_nv_n$$
$$T(0) = T(a_1v_1 + ... + a_nv_n)$$
$$0 = a_1Tv_1 +...+a_nTv_n$$

Because $a_1=...=a_n = 0$,  $Tv_1,...,Tv_n$ is linearly independent. **And I don't know where I used the property of injectivity.**

Comment: If $T$ is injective then what is $ker(T)$?

Comment: is Ker(T) means Null(T)? is that ${0}$?

Comment: Is $\ker(T)=Null(T)$? Yes. Too answer "is that $0$?", for a linear map, $T(0)=0$ always and in addition $T$ is given to be injective, so does there exist $x\in V,\;x\neq0$ such that $T(x)=0$. If so what assumption will be violated?

Comment: @YadatiKiran Injectivity?

Comment: Yes. And the rest follows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any linear map $T$ one has $T(0)=0$. Further if $T$ is injective, (1-1 function) no other vector can be sent to zero by $T$. Hence $T(\sum a_ivi)=0$ implies $\sum a_iv_i=0$.